# C# Unity Animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There was a problem with Unity animations. When the character jumps, the animation is played, but if the character jumps in either direction, the animation does not stop and the character with this animation rolls on the ground.

https://ibb.co/hLKmK6W

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 10f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public int jump = 350 ;
    Animator animation;
    private bool inground;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animation = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jump);
            animation.SetTrigger("Jump");

        }
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveX * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (animation)
        {
            animation.SetBool("Run", Mathf.Abs(moveX) >= 0.1f);
        }
        Vector3 charecterScale = transform.localScale;
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            charecterScale.x = -7.215315f;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            charecterScale.x = 7.215315f;
        }
        transform.localScale = charecterScale;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this would be to check if the player is grounded, using `Physics2D.Raycast()` or `Physics2D.OverlapCircle()` and passing it as a boolean to the animator, like this:

```
public float radius = .5f;
public Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, -.5f, 0);
public LayerMask layermask;

Animator animation;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    animation = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

bool IsGrounded() => Physics2D.OverlapCircle((Vector2)transform.position + offset, radius, layermask);

// to visualize the circle
void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position + (Vector3)offset, radius);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    animation.SetBool("isGrounded", IsGrounded());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you are grounded or not. there is an example in this video:

https://youtu.be/CSu7MWv8qEY

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).